# Calculation of distance of points with double coordinates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, console-application

While I was writing a c++ program I stuck on a problem. In brief, my program input is one integer which is the number of coordinates that I have to input. And I have an algorithm that calculates the passed distance between all of the points. Here is my algorithm:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14;
const double rightXLimit = 5;
const double leftXLimit = -5;
const double topYLimit = 2;
const double bottomYLimit = -2;
const int ARR_SIZE = 100;

bool IsPointInRules(double x, double y)
{
    if ((x >= leftXLimit && x <= rightXLimit) && (y >= bottomYLimit && y <= topYLimit))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

double checkLimitsAndDistCalc(double x, double y, double x1, double y1)
{
    if (!(IsPointInRules(x, y) || IsPointInRules(x1, y1)))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (IsPointInRules(x, y) && (!IsPointInRules(x1, y1)))
    {
        if (x1 <= leftXLimit)
        {
            x1 = leftXLimit;
        }
        if (x1 >= rightXLimit)
        {
            x1 = rightXLimit;
        }
        if (y1 <= bottomYLimit)
        {
            y1 = bottomYLimit;
        }
        if (y1 >= topYLimit)
        {
            y1 = topYLimit;
        }
    }
    else if ((!IsPointInRules(x, y)) && IsPointInRules(x1, y1))
    {
        if (x <= leftXLimit)
        {
            x = leftXLimit;
        }
        if (x >= rightXLimit)
        {
            x = rightXLimit;
        }
        if (y <= bottomYLimit)
        {
            y = bottomYLimit;
        }
        if (y >= topYLimit)
        {
            y = topYLimit;
        }
    }
    double distance = sqrt(pow(x1 - x, 2) + pow(y1 - y, 2));
    double result = ((PI * distance / 2) + distance) / 2;

    //cout << setw(3) << x << setw(3) << y << setw(3) << x1 << setw(3) << y1 << " --> " << distance << " --> " << result << endl;

    return result;
}

double calculateDistance(double* arrOne, double* arrTwo, int n)
{
    double finalResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        double getDistance = checkLimitsAndDistCalc(arrOne[i], arrTwo[i], arrOne[i + 1], arrTwo[i + 1]);
        finalResult += getDistance;
    }
    return finalResult;
}

int main()
{
    double coordsArrX[ARR_SIZE];
    double coordsArrY[ARR_SIZE];
    int n;

    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> coordsArrX[i];
        cin >> coordsArrY[i];
    }

    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << calculateDistance(coordsArrX, coordsArrY, n) << '\n';

}
```

The problem is when I enter integers like coordinates the distance is wrong, but when enter double the distance is right and I can not find where is the problem. Here I tried some auto tests:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried entering a mix of integers and doubles?

Comment: No, I do not try such kind of combination.

Comment: What's the purpose of the expression `((PI * distance / 2) + distance) / 2;` ?

Comment: the movement between two points is not 
straight line, there may be a deviation.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I enter integers like coordinates the distance is wrong, but when enter double the distance is right and I can not find where is the problem.

That is an incorrect conclusion. The output is same whether you enter the coordinates using what appears to be integers or floating point numbers.

The output obtained using

```
7
0 0
0 3
-2 4
-1 1
-3 -1
4 1
6 3
```

is the same as using

```
7
0.0 0.0
0.0 3.0
-2.0 4.0
-1.0 1.0
-3.0 -1.0
4.0 1.0
6.0 3.0
```

See the output from using floating point input at http://ideone.com/fxgbga.

It appears that there is something else in your program that is not working as you are expecting.

Comment: Yes I tried input like that but as you can see the result is the same. There is something that break my code but I can not find it.

Comment: @DimitarGanichev, the only thing I can think of is that floating point comparisons, like you are using in `IsPointInRules` and `checkLimitsAndDistCalc`, are not reliable. You may want to compare them within some tolerance.